# How to fix "type uint256 is not implicitly convertible to expected uint256 storage ref"?

Tags: solidity

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract cool {
  
  uint[] public data;
  
   function set(uint _data) public {
     data = _data;
   }
  function see() public view returns(uint[] memory) {
      return data;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you append a new element to the end of an array:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract cool {
  
  uint[] public data;
  
   function set(uint _data) public {
     data.push(_data);
   }
  function see() public view returns(uint[] memory) {
      return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response..im only trying establish single value inside of the array. How do I do that?

Comment: data.push(_data);

Comment: Yep if you're trying to append a new value to the array push() is your answer

Comment: now im getting member "push" not found or not visible after argument dependent lookup in uint256[] storage ref from the compiler @KostiantynKurbatskyi

Comment: @Meriadoc reference compiler error above

Comment: .push() only works for individual elements--in the code above I turned _data into an array because I thought you wanted a new array. If you just want to append 1 new element to the existing array, you need to turn _data back into a normal uint (not an array) and then .push it into data